# When using emacs in screen, some keys are getting remapped

Tags: display, emacs

I start screen using the `-T` parameter and `xterm-256color` as value. This so i can use <kbd>CTRL-Up</kbd>, <kbd>CTRL-Down</kbd> and other functions in emacs which otherweise would just spout out garbage. Strangely, when I do this, the <kbd>end</kbd> is getting remapped to a select-key and it doesn't bring the cursor to the end-of-line anymore. This is not the case if I use screen without the `-T` argument.

I would like to know why this is, and why emacs in screen can't just work like in a normal bash.

Answer (score 0):

Emacs uses key bindings extensively, it is completely configurable via the .emacs file. I recommend spending a few moments on the tutorial : 
type `C-h t`  that is <kbd>ctrl</kbd> pressed with <kbd>h</kbd> followed by a <kbd>h</kbd> . It will go over navigation and basic commands which basically are not using the arrow keys or the rest of the keyboard navigation keys.

The reason you still can use the navigational keys depend on the terminal, but the emacs command work on all platforms and cross terminals (in principal...).

As for the emacs ideology, If you are interested in giving it the time, you can become fluent and much more productive.

Once you are proficient you could bind your keys whichever way you like (including your keyboard arrows) Have a look at melpa ( `M-x list-packages`) someone might have already made a package for that...